# Most efficient way to get has_many relationships of an array of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

A `product` has many `uploads`, and an `import` has many `products`.
I'd like to get all the uploads linked to the products of a given import.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
@import = Import.includes(products: [:uploads]).find(params[:id])
@products = @import.products
@uploads= @products.map{|product| product.uploads.where.not(file: nil)}.flatten
```

But it seems pretty inefficient. 
Is there other solution?

Comment: Do you need to load all the products and their uploads for your views or just manipulate the data?

Comment: I do need to load all the products and uploads for the view

Answer (score 3):

Since an `import` has many `products` i assume that a `product` belongs to an `import`; if so, you could try to query `products`, like this:

```
@uploads = Product.where(import_id: params[:id]).joins(:uploads).where.not(file: nil)
```

Comment: I like this better!

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
 @import = Import.includes(:products).find(params[:id])
 @products = @import.products.pluck(:id)
 @uploads = Upload.where(products_id: [@products]).where.not(file: nil)
```

Pluck avoids insantiating each record and grabs the id's directly from the database.  This should save time over instantiating each product with the `map` iterator.